# remove Border="0" inline Attribute of table generated by Asp:Datalist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, datalist

my code
    
        
        
        
            
                '>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>

which generate code like

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLID" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="pib_archives">
                <span><a href='#'>Dec 11, 2017</a></span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i want to remove **border="0"** on table
i have tried this script code

```
$('table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLID').removeAttr("border");
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLID').removeAttr("border");
```

tell me alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

You're using C# probably server side language, When it comes to the client side, we all know about ClientID which gives us a unique ClientID of control to refer on the client side. But so far it was read-only (you cannot set it in code).

Try this: it will probably target the desired element

```
$('<%= DLID.ClientID %>').css("border","")
```

Answer (score 1):

When I test your snippet, it generates html like this: `<table id="DLID">` without the border. This is in framework 4.5+

But you can remove it with jQuery `removeAttr`

```
$("#<%= DLID.ClientID %>").removeAttr("border");
```

Comment: <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLID" border="0">  still generates border="0"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var stl= $('table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLID').css("border","")
```